# How do I copy every key/value pairs from Dictionary<string, string> to IDictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

I'm trying to do as follows:

```
exception.Data = LoggedProperties;
```

But it's not accepted since the `Data` property on the exception classes has a private setter.

So I thought to proceed using `ForAll` on the first or the second Dictionary. But this class don't have a similar syntax.

And neither `Dictionary.Keys` allows for that.

They also don't have `AddRange`.

So how would you copy from one dictionary to the other one with a compact syntax?

I.e. using Linq or a lambda expression?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The `Dictionary` will implement that interface...

Comment: Dictionary<TKey, TValue> already IS an IDictionary

Comment: @mrlucmorin: yes, but I still need to do that. The reason is pretty simple. exception.Data has a private setter. So I can't do exception.Data = LoggedProperties

Comment: @Sam, what are you attempting to do? How does having something in interface form help you? Create your own exception to hold these details.

Comment: @Arran: I've clarified what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Sam, makes more sense now, have voted to get the question re-opened.

Comment: @Arran: thanks.. can I ask you a pleasure? **you see how people are often very hurried in downvoting**. This lead to my ban from meta :-( can you have a look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually/220719#220719 or here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213294/synonymize-modulus-and-modulo/222033#222033 and if you think it could be right upvote me?

Comment: @Sam, no offense, but your question got downvoted because it was badly formulated. I can understand if english is not your native tongue, but     you need to write clear and concise questions. Otherwise you get downvoted.

Comment: @mrlucmorin: for sure I'm not saying the question was pretty before.  But the biggest difference is that now it's clear the reason because I want to do that. Before people thought: "Dictionary<TKey, TValue> already IS an IDictionary". People are often (always?) hurried, but it's a mistake.. have a read at this book: http://www.amazon.com/Social-Intelligence-Science-Human-Relationships/dp/055338449X . it wasn't to close.

Comment: "People are often hurried" in your view because you assume that people are going to read your badly formed questions, think about the psychology behind it and ask themselves "what did he really mean with this question". Ain't going to happen, so get used to it. If 90% of people don't understand you, can you guess where the problem lies ?

Comment: It's still not very clear what you're asking? Are you trying to assign to a private property? You can't, that's the point of `private`. **OR** are you trying to put all key-value mappings from one dictionary into another? Which one is it?

Comment: @mrlucmorin: SE was a place were people answered questions, now is becoming a place where people close questions

Comment: @amon: no, I want to copy every keyvalue pair from the first dictionary to the second in just one line of code. The second one you said.

Comment: @Sam Questions we do answer. Gibberish we don't.

Comment: @mrlucmorin: I'm speaking of this in chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either wrap your exceptions in another - (since it's a `virtual` property, you can override it):

```
public class ExceptionTest : Exception
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> InternalData { get; set; }
    public ExceptionTest(Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        InternalData = data;
    }

    public override Dictionary<string, string> Data 
    {
        get 
        {
            return InternalData;
        }
    }
}
```

or you could also just iterate through the dictionary calling `.Data.Add` on each turn.

Neither are pretty though.

As for copying a dictionary, since both sides are dictionaries, it's easy, either:

```
var newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(originalDictionary);
```

or:

```
var newDictionary = originalDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: great idea! but you could also help me to put all key-value mappings from one dictionary into the other one without using for and foreach. I mean I want to do in a single line. Like using ForAll construct.

Comment: What you intend this copy to do? If I have 6 values in dictionary 1, and 9 values in dictionary 2, does dictionary then get 6 *more* values and have 15 in total or does dictionary 2 get *overwritten* entirely with 6 values?

Comment: The target dictionary will be empty. So I want to do exactly the same of: foreach(var p in LoggedProperties) {exception.Data.Add(p.Key, p.Value)}